# How can we trigger shift+click for vue js elements in browser console

Tags: jquery, vue.js

My project is developed in laravel-mix-vue framework.

So, I did a few UI functionalities on the Vue side.

For ex,

```
<template>
    //...
    <div @click.prevent="onClick($event)">click element</div>
    //...
</template>

<script>
   //...
   function onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        if(event.shiftKey){
            console.log('shift key pressed');
        }
   }
   //...
</script>
```

So, I want to trigger that "click element" div element click with the shift press.

I tried the below way. But that not working for me.

```
var shiftClick = jQuery.Event( "click", { shiftKey: true } );
$("#testing-div").trigger(shiftClick);
```

I want shift+click trigger script or any other way to call that "click element" div element click with shift press.

Comment: why did you put the `event: MouseEvent` on your parameter? I believe removing the `MouseEvent` along with the colon the code should work.

Comment: @Remicaster assuming he's using typescript, it shouldn't break anything, although his snippet is missing `lang="ts"` so you might be right.  Otherwise what I'm confused about is if the Vue onClick function works, then what is the purpose of needing a separate, seemingly redundant, jQuery function? jQuery is hardly ever necessary anymore in modern JS development let alone in a Vue project where direct DOM manipulation should be avoided as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution in javascript `dispatchEvent`.

```
function simulateClick({
  ctrl = false, alt = false, shift = false, meta = false
} = {}) {

  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ctrl, alt, shift, meta, 0, null);

  return evt;    
}

document.getElementById(...).dispatchEvent(simulateClick({shift: true}))
```

It's working for my scenarios. So now I can able to trigger the `shift+click` event for particular elements.